# RainLoop autorefresh emails interval values

Tags: javascript, webmail

I'm trying to change interval values for auto refresh for new emails (RainLoop webmail). I have found that INBOX is refreshed via

```
Events.sub('interval.2m', function () {
  self.folderInformation(Cache.getFolderInboxName());
});
```

but I was not able to find which value I need to adjust for other (shared) folders auto refresh intervals.

As far I have figured out that other folders are refreshed around 6th minute after application was launched and probably refresh is executed by `folderInformationMultiply()` call but creating

```
Events.sub('interval.1m', function () {
  self.folderInformationMultiply();
});
```

didn't solved my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It came up that `folderInformationMultiply()` is a correct function to call but within that function there was another function `getNextFolderNames` where was set another timeout interval for AJAX call for folders names/structure and that must be adjusted with a relevant value to